# Jupyter notebook (Anaconda) "load failed. save is disabled" error

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

Ever since I updated to the newest version of Anaconda (Navigator 1.2.1), I have had problems where I will be editing a file and then suddenly I can no longer save the file.  I get the message, `"Load failed.  Save is disabled."`  Sometimes restarting the kernel will solve this, but other times, I will quit everything, restart, duplicate the file, and still get this problem.  I've tried:

1. Changing file permissions, but that doesn't appear to solve the problem for me.
2. Uninstalling and reinstalling Anaconda.  This "Solves" the problem, but the problem recurs again with new files.  I don't think I can keep uninstalling and reinstalling my different environments.
3. Changing Browsers.  Many solutions that I can find online discuss looking at the javascript output for the browser.  However, I open the file in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox and get the same problem in all of them.

Any ideas why I would get this "Save is disabled" message in Jupyter?  More importantly, what is causing it and how do I prevent it from occurring?